# my background worker block the main thread c#

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am trying to upload many files Using c# file up-loader and enable the user to stop the process in the middle so I create backgroundworker to run upload on it but the cancellation button does not work (it fires after all the files is uploaded)and WorkerThread_ProgressChanged does not affect UI elements and the label text doesnot change and this is my code

```
protected void cancelupload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    workerThread.CancelAsync();
    if (workerThread.CancellationPending)
    {
    }


}

private void WorkerThread_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Uploadpercentage.Text= "Uploading... (" + e.ProgressPercentage + "%)";
}
private void WorkerThread_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        // lblStopWatch.Text = "Cancelled";
    }
    else
    {
        //  lblStopWatch.Text = "Stopped";
    }
}
private void WorkerThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    _keepRunning = true;
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Unuploaded_files = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() { };
    int count = 0;
    while (_keepRunning && count < fileCollection.Count)
    {

        HttpPostedFile uploadfile = fileCollection[count];
        String fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadfile.FileName);
        string fileExxtension = Path.GetExtension(uploadfile.FileName);
        if (ValidExtensions.Contains(fileExxtension))
        {
            if (File.Exists(Chosen_Site_Path + @"\" + Selected_folder_name.SelectedItem.Text + @"\" + fileName))
        {
            KeyValuePair<string, string> Unuploaded_file = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(fileName, "Another file exists with the same name!");
            Unuploaded_files.Add(Unuploaded_file);
        }
        else
        {
            uploadfile.SaveAs(Chosen_Site_Path + @"\" + Selected_folder_name.SelectedItem.Text + @"\" + fileName);
            log.INSERT_ACTIVITY_LOG(Session["User_PK"].ToString(), Session["User_Type"].ToString(), "Uploader Home Page : Uploaded " + fileName + "Selected site " + BASF_SITE_ID);
            log.INSERT_SITE_HISTORY(Session["User_PK"].ToString(), BASF_SITE_ID, "Uploaded file: " + fileName);
        }
    }
        else
        {
        KeyValuePair<string, string> Unuploaded_file = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(fileName, "File type is not allowed");
        Unuploaded_files.Add(Unuploaded_file);

    }
    count++;

        string timeElapsedInstring = (DateTime.Now - startTime).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");

        int percent = (int)(((Decimal)count / fileCollection.Count ) *100);
        workerThread.ReportProgress(percent, timeElapsedInstring);

        if (workerThread.CancellationPending)
        {
            // this is important as it set the cancelled property of RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs to true
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (Unuploaded_files.Count == 0)
    {

        string message = "alert('Files Uploaded')";
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(submitupload, this.GetType(), "alert", message, true);
    }
    else
    {
        string msg = "UNUPLOADED FILES:" + @"\" + "n";
        for (int i = 0; i < Unuploaded_files.Count; i++)
        {
            msg += Unuploaded_files[i].Key + ": " + Unuploaded_files[i].Value + @"\" + "n";
        }
        string alertmsg = "alert('" + msg + "')";
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(submitupload, this.GetType(), "alert", alertmsg, true);
    }
    viewSites();
}
```

Comment: If the UI thread was blocked you woudn't be able to even click on a button. Your code contains *ASP.NET* specific calls like `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`. There's no main thread in an ASP.NET application and each request runs on a separate thread already. You don't need a BGW in this case

Comment: How about creating a boolean variable, assigning it to false initially and checking if it is true in your while loop. Of course you have to make it true when cancel button is clicked.

Comment: You are coding for web trying to use desktop paradigm, If you want to upload files asynchronously on a web application, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously

Comment: I don't see any reason to downvote the question, even it the OP efforts seems to be on a wrong direction, at least is doing an effort and asking properly

Comment: the main problem is that the code inside cancelupload_Click doesnot execute until do_work function finish its work and WorkerThread_ProgressChanged function change the label-text after do_work function finish its work so they are  not working on parallel so the do_work will never stop at the middle

Comment: @DanielBrughera would you please explain to me why this paradigm will not work with web

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos already did it

Answer (score -1):

This situation is called a race condition and is a common concern in multithreaded programming. For more information about multithreading design issues, see [Managed Threading Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/managed-threading-best-practices?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Is not race condition, is ASP.Net